# Why var value not show in id element?

Tags: javascript

Why var value not show in id element ?

I try many time but not work , How can i do that ?

```
<script>
var xxxx = "test";
//alert(xxxx);
document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = xxxx;
</script>
<span id="here"></span>
```

Comment: Because the `#here` element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Probably because the DOM element does not exist when you try to access it by code

Comment: Did you take a look at the console?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> ```
> <span id="here"></span>
> <script>
> var xxxx = "test";
> //alert(xxxx);
> document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = xxxx;
> </script>
> ```

And have a look at [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element), as @Teemu suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're trying to reference the element `here` before it's defined. Put your `script` tags under your `span` tag and it should work.